# Microsoft Graph API delegated permission -Access Token NodeJs

Tags: node.js, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph Bookings API,a delegated permission.Can someone help me how to get access token for delegated permissions it is of grant_type="authorization_code" in NodeJs.
I have accessed the graph API for application permissions and got access_token for grant_type "client_credentials", code below

```
   const getToken = async () => {
    const postData = {
        client_id:.MS_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: MS_GRAPH_SCOPE,
        client_secret: MS_GRAPH_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type:MS_GRAPH_GRANT_TYPE 
    };

    const response = await client.post(MS_GRAPH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
        querystring.stringify(postData),
        {
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, I am facing a similar issue, I want to send messages to a channel and this only works with delegated permissions, the token I generated using https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token and using the default scope i.e. https://graph.microsoft.com/.default informs the Microsoft Identity platform of Application Permissions only, how do I modify the POST request to generate a token to  work with delegated permissions ?